# How to include namespace2's same function name in namespace's 1 without compile errors?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to call namespace2's function from while defining namespace1's function **in a different file**. The issue is it doesn't work if they are not located inside of the same file! I am using MinGWx64 compiler

Main.cpp

```cpp
#include "Foo.h"
int main()
{
    name1::func();
}
```

Foo.h

```cpp
#ifndef DEF_FLAG_
#include "Foo2.cpp"
namespace name1
{
    void func()
    {
        name2::func();
    }
}
#define DEF_FLAG_
#endif
```

Foo2.cpp

```
namespace name2
{
    void func()
    {

    }
}
```

trying to call a function in another namespace from another file like in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm . But from another file. I don't understand the point of namespaces if the compiler doesn't respect them when I specified them inside of namespaces

Comment: There should be a forward declaration in a `Foo2.h`, and that included instead of `#include "Foo2.cpp"`.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing the `#define DEF_FLAG_` late? It seems like you did this deliberately. You know that it is supposed to go right under the `#ifndef` to guard, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo seems to be fixed when moving the includes inside of the namespace. I don't know why this is or if it's a fluke so I won't post the answer as I am not that smart in c++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for your help on #define flags. I wasn't sure if it was suppose to be at the beginning or end of the header

Comment: @SUBBASTION Please note, that `#include "Foo2.cpp"` is still fundamentally wrong.

Comment: The naming of the files show your *intentions*. If you intend to `#include` a file, you should name it ending in `.h`. If you instead plan to compile the file separately, the name should end in `.cpp`. And no file should be used both ways.

Comment: Add the exact error message to the question. "it doesn't work" asks people to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.h --> Foo.cpp --> Foo2.h --> Foo2.cpp` where no implementations are in the header files. this will cause weird errors if a cpp trys to include another cpp while defining itself even with safegaurds it throws a fit while importing windows.h